# how to get url in JEST for Angular?

Tags: angular, ts-jest, angular14

Good afternoon colleagues!!! I turn to you because I don't know what else to do hahaha, I tell you that within my code I have the following section.

Depending on the path where I am standing is some functionality that my component does. But, I need to test this with JEST for unit testing.
The thing is that I am not being able to test well, because with any way that I try to test it returns an empty url. jest.spyOn doesn't work for me or doesn't do anything.
In my company they decided to use JEST and not JASMINE, so the test is costing me more.

do you have any suggestions for this?

Thank you ❤️

[Image with code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3JrQ.png)

probe spyOn, url con ts-ignore, etc.